# How to write JUnit test cases with ignoring database activities

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, testcase

The following is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/ds-context.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PaidListTest {

    @Autowired
    PaymentService paymentService;

    @Test
    public void getPaidList() {
        List<PaymentGetServiceDO> response = null;
        try {
            response = paymentService.setPaidStatusList();          
            if(response != null && response.size() > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++){
                    assertNotNull(response.get(i).getAgentcode());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the DAO layer of the service call **paymentService.setPaidStatusList()** have some operations with database activities of save and update, like `em.merge(renewalPoliciesDO);`  
 But I don't want to execute them while calling the test method, they needs to get called only when actual business logic is called. 
How can I restrict or rollback the database transactions here?
The service and DAO methods are tedious here. However, I have simplified them for your reference.
 ***Service method***
`if(!updateList.isEmpty()){
HashMap<String,String> recordset = new HashMap<String,String>();
    recordset = paymentDAO.setRenewalStatus(updateList);
}`
***DAO implementation***

```
if(paymentUpdateResDO.getPaymentstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("MANUAL") && 
!responseUpdateStatus.getPolicystatusid().equals(renewedStatusId)){
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Integer> payQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Integer.class);
Root<PaymentStatusDO> payRoot = payQuery.from(PaymentStatusDO.class);
payQuery.multiselect(payRoot.get("paymentstatusid"));
payQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(payRoot.get("paymentstatusdescription"), "Manual"));
Integer paymentStatusId = em.createQuery(payQuery).getSingleResult();
insertOldPolicy(responseUpdateStatus);
responseUpdateStatus.setNewpolicyno(paymentUpdateResDO.getNewpolicyno());
responseUpdateStatus.setPreviousstatusid(responseUpdateStatus.getPolicystatusid());
responseUpdateStatus.setPolicystatusid(renewedStatusId);
Timestamp modifiedDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
responseUpdateStatus.setModifieddatetime(modifiedDate);
responseUpdateStatus.setModifiedby("RPA");
responseUpdateStatus.setPaymentstatusid(paymentStatusId);
responseUpdateStatus.setActiveindicator("Y");
em.merge(responseUpdateStatus);
successRecords++;
}
```

In my case, I need the result arraylists, but the `em.merge` and `em.persist` activities need to be ignored.

When I try with `MockitoJUnitRunner` as `@GauravRai1512` preferred, I get my testcase executed but the program is terminated so that I am unable to get the result ArrayLists.
[image: Screenshot for successful execution of testcase] 
 ***Refer this image*** [image: Program terminated, so that nothing got executed]

Comment: you have written assertNotNull(response.get(i).getAgentcode()) this so it will give you only success and failure. it will not give you any value as junit is for to test your code logic behaviour.

Comment: Should I remove assertNotNull() to get my methods run? I have tried that too. But it's still terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow below approach as suggested by Pooja Aggarwal.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class PaidListTest {

        @Mock
        PaymentService paymentService;

        @Before
          public void setUp() {
             MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
             mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
             List<PaymentGetServiceDO> response = new ArrayList<PaymentGetServiceDO>();
}
        @Test
        public void getPaidList() {
            List<PaymentGetServiceDO> response = null;
            try {
                response = paymentService.setPaidStatusList();          
                if(response != null && response.size() > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++){
                        assertNotNull(response.get(i).getAgentcode());
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will not execute your save and update operation.

Comment: I get this exception while trying the method: `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Field 'paymentService' annotated with @InjectMocks is null.`
Please make sure the instance is created *before* MockitoAnnotations.initMocks();
Example of correct usage:
   `class SomeTest {
      @InjectMocks private Foo foo = new Foo();
      
      @Before public void setUp() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);`

Comment: @VengatJoy can you please check again?i have changed the code.also can you share setPaidStatusList() code.

Comment: can you share paymentService class with setPaidStatusList() method?

Comment: @VengatJoy you have written assertNotNull(response.get(i).getAgentcode() this so it will give you only success and failure. it will not give you any value as junit is for to test your code logic behaviour.

Comment: @VengatJoy as your concern has been resolved so can you please upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: Should I remove assertNotNull() to get my methods run? I have tried that too. But it's still terminated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183536/discussion-between-vengat-joy-and-gauravrai1512).

Answer (score 2):

You can use mocking of the database calls. You can write test cases using Jmockit where you can mock the call of database which will prevent save or update operation in the database.

You can learn writing jmockit test cases from http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html

Or

https://winterbe.com/posts/2009/08/18/introducing-jmockit/

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you can either:

- Mock the `PaymentService` so that you can define exactly what to do on each of the calls to it. In this case, you would simply return a hard-coded `List<PaymentGetServiceDO>` response, and your test could do something with that.  The downside of this is that you're not *really* testing `PaymentService` in that case.  You're simply looking at hard-coded data, and doing something with it.  In my view, that's not a valid test.
- Or, you can instantiate a `PaymentService` object with either an in-memory database, only for use with tests, or with a mock DB object, where you can then define exactly how to respond to each of the `merge`, `save`, `update` and similar operations.  If the `PaymentService` object doesn't allow this, then it should be redesigned so it accepts as a parameter a Database/Connection, which would be the normal `@Autowired` injected parameter when running in production, but which you can instantiate manually when testing.  This would be  a proper test, since you'd be validating the rest of the logic inside `setPaidStatusList`, but you're not actually hitting a database to achieve that.

Comment: Do you say that the first option is not the correct way to do the testing? But I need the executed hard-coded ArrayList response.